# I want update in summary section, item name and price when click on add (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, addition, price

I want to update the summary section with the item name,
and item price, I do that but each time I click on add, remove the old one and updated with the new

booking.component.html

```
<table class="container table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Activity</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">1 hour</th>
        <th scope="col">30 min.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of bookAdd">
        <td>img</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let pointer of item.price; index as i">
          {{ pointer }}
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
            (click)="addTotalPrice(pointer)"
            (click)="addName(item.name)"
            (click)="addPrice(pointer)"
          >
            Add
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 card">
        <h3 class="center">summary</h3>
        <p>
         {{name}} {{price}} 
        </p>
        <h4>total {{ total }}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

booking.component.ts

```
   bookAdd: Booking[] = [];
   total = 0;
    name:  any;
    price: any;
 
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.booking.getBooking().subscribe((data) => {
      this.bookAdd = data;
      console.log(this.bookAdd);
    });


  }

  addTotalPrice(price: number ,) {
    this.total += price;

  }
  addName(name:any ) {

    this.name = name;
  }
  addPrice (price: number) {
    this.price = price;
  }
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lIjWCVvz-iSm9MlHxWXLOA2c_Hka6SrB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I refactored a little bit.

1. Do not add multiple listeners for methods, instead add methods to listener `(click)="method(); otherMethod()"`
2. Do not forget to unsubscribe, I am using `takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)`
3. Do not forget to implement all members `implements OnInit`

Html:

```html
<table class="container table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Activity</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">1 hour</th>
      <th scope="col">30 min.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let book of books">
      <td>img</td>
      <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          *ngIf="!addedBooks.includes(book)"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
          (click)="addBook(book)"
        >
          Add
        </button>
        <span *ngIf="addedBooks.includes(book)">(added!)</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 card">
      <h3 class="center">summary</h3>
      <p>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let addedBook of addedBooks">
          {{ addedBook.name }} {{ addedBook.price }}
        </ng-container>
      </p>
      <h4>total {{ totalPrice }}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  books: Book[] = [];
  addedBooks: Book[] = [];
  totalPrice: number;
  unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  mockData = [
    { name: 'Lord of the Rings', price: 50 },
    { name: 'Dune', price: 100 },
  ];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    of(this.mockData)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.books = data;
        console.log(this.books);
      });
  }

  addBook(book: Book) {
    this.addedBooks.push(book);

    let sum = 0;
    this.addedBooks.forEach((book) => {
      sum += book.price;
    });
    this.totalPrice = sum;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
  }
}

export interface Book {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-irn9to?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thank you for helping, I have to prices for each item price for 1h and price for 30min

Comment: Tricky... so its a string `1h` and `30min` - any more variations? Can't you convert `prices` this to a more reasonable data structure? Like Duration, Number etc.

Comment: this is the jason data
[
  {
    "name": "Jet ski",
    "price": [600, 250],
    
  },
  {
    "name": "Banana boat",
    "price": [330, 330],
    
  {
    "name": "Dount",
    "price": [330, 330],
    
  }
]

Comment: So what does `[330, 330]` mean in your context? Why there are two numbers and what they represent?